# Analytics Scripts Insufficient Permission from Google Sheets

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to write a script to grab Google Analytics data & add it to a Google Sheet.

When running the following code, I get the following error on the sheet:

"User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."

Just a few quick check-box items:
Yes, I have admin permissions for the Analytics account I'm trying to access
Yes, I have admin permissions for the Google Sheet from which I'm creating the script
Yes, I've double-checked my current Google login to make sure I'm on the right account.

Here is the code:

```
function runDemo() {
  try {
    var results = getReportDataForProfile();
    outputToSpreadsheet(results);

  } catch(error) {
Browser.msgBox(error.message);
  }
}

function getReportDataForProfile() {
  var profileId = 'xxxxxxxx'; //firstProfile.getId();
  var tableId = 'ga:' + profileId;
  var startDate = getLastNdays(14);   // 2 weeks (a fortnight) ago.
  var endDate = getLastNdays(0);      // Today.

  var optArgs = {
'dimensions': 'ga:keyword',              // Comma separated list of dimensions.
'sort': '-ga:sessions,ga:keyword',       // Sort by sessions descending, then keyword.
'segment': 'dynamic::ga:isMobile==Yes',  // Process only mobile traffic.
'filters': 'ga:source==google',          // Display only google traffic.
'start-index': '1',
'max-results': '250'                     // Display the first 250 results.
  };

  // Make a request to the API.
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
  tableId,                    // Table id (format ga:xxxxxx).
  startDate,                  // Start-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
  endDate,                    // End-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
  'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews', // Comma seperated list of metrics.
  optArgs);

  if (results.getRows()) {
return results;

  } else {
    throw new Error('No views (profiles) found');
  }
}
```

Comment: At which level do you have GA admin access: Account, Property, or View? There is a difference between them.

Comment: I've got admin access at all levels. Verified at all levels.

Comment: Also, If I use a Google Analytics report generator tool from Google Sheets, I can access everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I screwed around with this for a while and then it started working.

My best guess is I copied the property ID from Google Analytics wrong. After going back and recopying it, everything worked well.